# How to add one more object and key to an existing NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary from the parsed json data and I want to keep all the objects and keys in that dictionary and also want to add another key value pair to the same dictionary.
How can I do that? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: convert it to mutable dictionary , then you can add more object to it.

Comment: In lieu of finding a suitable duplicate: `NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy]; mutableDictionary[key] = object; dictionary = [mutableDictionary copy];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify NSDictionary- you need to create an [NSMutableDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with the objects from the NSDictionary you have, then add new objects and their keys in the NSMutableDictionary using [setObject:forKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject%3aforKey%3a)   or  [setValue:forKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setValue%3aforKey%3a).

Answer (score 2):

In NSJSONSerializer, look at the [NSJSONReadingOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2) that you can pass to the parser.

There is one *NSJSONReadingMutableContainers*  that makes the parser return mutable containers. So you get an NSMutableDictionary instead of an NSDictionary, and then it's just basic use of an NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: I had a quick look at this and it does indeed make the returned object a mutable object. In my test a I declared the object using `id` and got it's class after : __NSDictionaryM